# Android UI issue - Bottom button scrolls up above the keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm facing a problem with android UI, that when keyboard appears the button in the bottom also pops-up above the keyboard. I would like to scroll the edittext(only edittext) when keyboard appears. Here is my xml code, Could any one please help me?
I already tried with adjustPan - it scrolls the toolbar along with the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="1.0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/l_layout">
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp">
                <requestFocus></requestFocus>
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go next page"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info. 
In the android Manifest.xml file, add the following.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Please read the question again, //// I already tried with adjustPan - it scrolls the toolbar along with the screen.//// I don't want the toolbar to be scrolled

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your button by keyboard then use this code below, I just edited your code -

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"></EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Go next page" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

but you can scroll to make show your button..

Comment: My issue is the button also pops up along with the keyborad. I want the button fixed on the bottom of the screen always whatever happens

Comment: Button ig getting hide. seems like its going beyond the screen. I would like to make the button visible on screen(fixed at bottom of the screen) same time it should not be popup along with the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this one.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.partharaj.ggpd.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:hint="Name"/>

            ....

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: No, the button should not be popup along with keyboard.

Comment: Not working. 2 issues. 1. EditTexts are not scrolling up 2. Button popup along with keyboard.

Comment: I got it and i did the same, but no luck :(

Comment: OK then try adding the attribute `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to the ScrollView.

Comment: Wooow this is fine. but possible to prevent toolbar moving up? Tool bar moving up when keyboard pop-up

Comment: Great to hear that it resolved your problem. OK let me check about the toolbar issue, can I see the style applied on the app or activity?

Comment: No styles we applied, Its default one we are using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
`

Comment: The `adjustPan` property should prevent pushing the toolbar, if didn't you may try to apply the adjustPan programmatically after initiating the toolbar inside onCreate() like this, `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Comment: No, still facing the issue that toolbar pops up when keyboard appears.

Answer (score 0):

Do this as

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layour_alignBottom="@id/ScrollView01">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go next page"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It will align you relative layour below scroll view

Answer (score 0):

try adding below code in your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: That will make the button appears above the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your layout with

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

and it seems to work successfully.

Comment: But when i place cursor on edittext, the edtibox wont scroll up. Thats the issue